# Find infinite loops (expressions) in a string

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a text that should check for loops in which the condition is true, then I have to replace them to prevent infinite loops. I would also like to know if there is another method.

Current function code:

```js
function whileReplacer(text){
        
        var regex = /while\s*\(([^\)]+)\)/, hasLoops = text.match(regex), whileCondition;
        if(!hasLoops) return text;

        whileCondition = hasLoops[1];

        var isTrueCondition;

        try{
            isTrueCondition = !!eval(whileCondition);
            if(isTrueCondition){ //replacing infinite loop
                text = text.replace(regex, "while(false)");
                console.info("Infinite loop was detected, replaced to =>", text);
            }
        }catch(error){ 
            console.warn("Error evaluating condition =>", whileCondition, error); 
        }

        return text;
    }

    //Text with containing infinite loops

    whileReplacer("while(true){alert(1)}");  //ok

    whileReplacer("while(1);"); //ok

    whileReplacer("while(1+("{"+5)){alert(1)}"); //Condition syntax error
    
    whileReplacer("while(1+')'){alert(1)}"); //Condition syntax error
```

**EDIT:**

Currently I use `/while\([^\)]+\)/.replace("while(false)")` and it works for examples like `foo;while(true){};baz`, `;foo;faa;while(1+1){};foo;faa`

But what happens if there are parentheses within the search?, Example:

`while(1+("{"+5)){alert(1)}` It should be replaced as `while(false){alert(1)}`

`while(1+')'){alert(1)}` It should be replaced as `while(false){alert(1)}`

Comment: What is the expected use case here? The `eval` may be more dangerous than what it's trying to prevent.

Comment: @PaulS.  I know, is just a sample of example, I put the `eval` expressions, no problem with that

Comment: Regular expressions cannot correctly match nested balanced parentheses of any form. A parser will be needed if you need nested parentheses matching.

Comment: You can do this with a pcre/perl style engine or even dot-net using balanced groups. PCRE style: `\((?>[^()]+|(?R))*\)` Unfortunately with JS, you don't stand a chance.

Answer (score 2):

You should not use regex alone to do this task. This is a job for a parser... https://github.com/marijnh/acorn

You should be able to parse your input strings, and then walk the AST, replacing the condition of the while loop in a more robust way.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't really a way to do this generically with regex; expressions that evaluate to 'true' aren't describable with a regular language, so you can't match them with a regular expression. You can make a set of expressions you don't ever want to run, but you can't get complete coverage.

Comment: I think I explained wrong, the purpose of this question is to find strings as while(text) ex:  `while(<<match>>){foo}; if(1){ while(<<match>>){} }`